# Calculating Density in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, primes

I have the following code which takes 2 inputs: an upper and lower limit. This then calculates the number of primes between the upper and lower.

For example: `Upper = 100, lower = 0`, so the number of primes is 25.

```
lower = int(input("Enter lower range: "))
upper = int(input("Enter upper range: "))
total = 0
print("Prime numbers between",lower,"and",upper,"are:")

for num in range(lower,upper + 1):
   # prime numbers are greater than 1
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(num)
           total = total + 1

print("total primes found", total)
```

I want to calculate the density of primes, so the density between 0-100 would be 25%. I'm not 100% sure if that's actually the density or the frequency. (I`ve been asked to find the density, *not* the frequency.)

I was thinking something along these line `(upper - lower) / total`.  That's obviously not the correct expression to calculate the density, but I can't seem to get my head around how I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the proportion of primes over the given range.  You are almost correct.

```
total / float(upper - lower + 1)
```

Comment: this has given me and output of `0.24752475247524752` this cant be correct as its 25? or am i missing something

Comment: You gave a lower limit of 0.  Since this range includes 101 integers, how do you get a correct answer of 25% ?  If you include only one of the endpoints, then remove the `+1`.

Comment: Ah I see, my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From 0 to 100 there are 101 integers, so the density should be 25/101, but not 25%, it equals `total/float(upper-lower+1)` and float is because `int/int` will return a integer but not a float